# Knative service http timeout setting

Tags: kubernetes, knative, knative-serving

What settings are required to ensure that the queue-proxy doesn't timeout in 60 seconds?
My http requests timeout in 60 seconds and the queue-proxy has these error messages

```
{"level":"error","ts":"2020-02-27T11:44:58.886Z","logger":"queueproxy","caller":"network/error_handler.go:31","msg":"error reverse proxying request; sockstat: sockets: used 375\nTCP: inuse 5 orphan 1 tw 95 alloc 54 mem 7\nUDP: inuse 0 mem 3\nUDPLITE: inuse 0\nRAW: inuse 0\nFRAG: inuse 0 memory 0\n","commit":"96cffff","knative.dev/key":"playground-flows-master/sleeper-service-pclb2","knative.dev/pod":"sleeper-service-pclb2-deployment-6bc5479789-gzmcj","error":"context canceled","stacktrace":"knative.dev/serving/pkg/network.ErrorHandler.func1\n\t/home/prow/go/src/knative.dev/serving/pkg/network/error_handler.go:31\nnet/http/httputil.(*ReverseProxy).ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go:251\nknative.dev/serving/pkg/queue.(*requestMetricHandler).ServeHTTP\n\t/home/prow/go/src/knative.dev/serving/pkg/queue/request_metric.go:71\nmain.handler.func1\n\t/home/prow/go/src/knative.dev/serving/cmd/queue/main.go:197\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2007\nknative.dev/serving/pkg/queue.ForwardedShimHandler.func1\n\t/home/prow/go/src/knative.dev/serving/pkg/queue/forwarded_shim.go:100\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2007\nknative.dev/serving/pkg/queue.(*timeoutHandler).ServeHTTP.func1\n\t/home/prow/go/src/knative.dev/serving/pkg/queue/timeout.go:80"}
```

The versions and settings are as follows.

Knative version v0.11.0

Istio version: 1.3.5

KnativeService:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sleeper-service
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: "1"
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 0
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MILLISECONDS
          value: "330000"
        image: <image>
        name: user-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: http1
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 0
        resources: {}
      timeoutSeconds: 500
  traffic:
  - latestRevision: true
    percent: 100
```

When the maxScaling is set to 1 and if each request is taking more that 60 seconds, the other requests which are in the queue are getting timedout.

Answer (score 0):

This is a client side timeout most likely. Looking at your service, it will timeout internally after 500s if no response data is sent at all.

```
"error":"context canceled"
```

is usually the giveaway.